# Has Wolverine ever played a major part in an Avengers storyline?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, wolverine

Wanda Maximoff (and by extension,  her brother Pietro) feature in both X-men and Marvel movie continuity. This is largely because she's plays an integral role in at least one large Avengers story line: Avengers Disassembled.

Has Wolverine ever had such a central role to an Avengers storyline,  and if so which was the first? Is this before Marvel and Fox made their deal about who gets which characters?

Comment: side note: Wanda has been part of a lot more than just one big Avengers storyline: she has been a member of the Avengers off and on since ~1965, and steadily since I believe the early 70s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Avengers and the X-men have quite a long history dating back to the late sixties. However, Wolverine doesn't become a member of the X-men until Giant-Sized X-men #1 in 1975. His first real intense interaction with the Avengers is during the Secret Wars in 1984.

[image]

- While the lineup was not purely an Avengers/Xmen lineup (members of the Fantastic Four, the Avengers, and the X-men as well as assorted villains were there as well, sparks flew between Wolverine and Captain America. Technically all of these heroes battled against the menace of the Universe-destroying Beyonder!

[image]

- Granted this isn't the first time these two heroes have come to blows, but it certainly wouldn't be the last. During the next few years, the Marvel Universe would have a number of major crossovers where different teams would meet, mingle and fight world-class evils.

[image]

- One of the very next major encounters between the X-men and the Avengers (and just about every other hero team on Earth is the Doomsday storyline in Rom #65, (1985) when the Dire Wraiths were attacking the Earth. Both teams put aside their differences to battle the shapechanging menace of the Dire Wraiths during the Wraith War.

[image]

- **All of these interactions occurred long before Marvel sold the rights to the X-men in the 1990s.**

Comment: This makes it clear that Wolverine has been in the same comic as the Avengers before. I don't see anything about what role he might have played in any particular storyline, or if that role was major.

Comment: Fighting the Beyonder counts as major in anyone's book, since he did attempt to destroy reality. As for a major role, very few characters get to play a singular role in Avengers stories since the book is primarily an ensemble book, which tries to give equal time to everyone. Wolverine wasn't even an Avenger until after the year 2005. So if he shows up in an Avenger book as a pivotal member, it isn't going to happen until he is a full-time member.

Answer (score 2):

One major event they met in was the [Avengers vs X-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_vs._X-Men) storyline, which is similar to the [Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War_(comics)) idea in that you have two groups of heroes with very different ideas about how best to protect Earth/people.

> The series focuses on the return of the Phoenix Force, the cosmic entity of death and rebirth, as it looks for its new host, believed to be the teenage mutant Hope Summers, who will possess all of its power. Cyclops and the other X-Men want to protect her and prepare her as if she's to be the mutant savior, while Captain America and the Avengers want her handed over to them so they can figure out what to do with her and keep the world safe from a potentially deadly fate. Brubaker described the series as "...one of those legendary ideas: What if the Avengers fought the X-Men?". Marvel's editor-in-chief Axel Alonso said "You've got two populations whose motivations are simple and understandable and defensible. That's part of the beauty of this. You're seeing a story that evolves out of 'What would you do?'"

[image]

Ultimately, Wolverine has to choose between two sides (hence why he's in the middle of this and some other covers from the series)